# Do the words “avalanche” and “avaler” have common etymology?

Tags: étymologie

Since **avalanche** is a huge amount of snow swallowing stuff and **avaler** means **to swallow**, I wonder if they have the same origin. (They also look quite alike and the *participe présent* is even closer: **avalant**)

Also, if someone could mention a good online etymology french dictionary (english ones are welcome too!), I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It would seem that “avaler” first meant “descendre” ; avalanche definitely as nothing to do with a mass of snow swallowing stuff. There might be another common origin, though, but the TLF ([avaler](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avaler), [avalanche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avalanche)) doesn’t seem to go that way. I’ll try looking a bit further, but I unfortunately don’t have any *Grand Robert* or other “large” dictionary at my disposal.

Comment: Just [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/avaler) in english answers for you ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bien qu’Édouard ait donné la réponse étymologique, il y a une corrélation euphonique autour du mot *aval* :

- Une péniche qui va de l'amont (du point le plus haut) vers l'aval (le point le plus bas) est une péniche *avalante*,  qui descend un cours d'eau.
- Faire descendre rapidement du gosier à l'estomac est *avaler* (sauf accident) de la nourriture.
- La neige qui part du sommet et descend en masse vers la vallée est une *avalanche*.

Que ce soit un bateau sur une rivière qui se déplace lentement, de la nourriture dans l'œsophage qui va rapidement ou un champ de neige qui déboule furieusement vers la vallée, tous ces objets en mouvements suivent une direction descendante... vers le *val*... ils vont *à val*.

Answer (score 4):

According to Le Petit Robert (dépôt légal 2001), *Avaler* is derived from “aval” (downhill), and got the sense of swallowing only later. “aval” comes from “a” and ”val”, ”val” intern come from the latin “vallis”, which means valley.

“Avalanche”, on the other hand, is a deformation of the word "lavanche” (apparently *because of* “aval”), which itself comes from the Savoyard word “lavantse” and the Latin “labina”, which means collapse, landslide<sup>1</sup>.

It would thus seem that any potential common root for “avaler” et ”avalanche” is anterior to Latin.

---

1. It’s a translation through French, so quite possibly inaccurate. The only Latin-English dictionary I found only talks of “marsh, fen”, which doesn’t match the other (Googled) sources I could find in French.